# SQL display one entry from table one, then display all the entries corresponding, no repeats?

Tags: php, sql, xml, phpmyadmin, rss

This is my first time using SQL, I'm using PHPMyAdmin. My connection to the database works fine.

I have 8 database tables, but I'm currently just trying to display the data from 5 of them. [This is my ER model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO3eY.png). I want to display city, place, photo and cat tables in an RSS feed.

Currently when load up the XML it repeats some of the entries, for example for each place it repeats the city information. So for place 1 it shows all the city data, then the place data, and the same for place 2 ect.[This is what the first few entries for the current output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozsA8.png), it's a long XML file due to the repeats.

I want the city information to be displayed once, then the corresponding place data to be displayed after. So City 1, then place 1,2,3,4,5,6 (as they correspond to city 1), then City 2, then place 7,8,9,10 (as they correspond to city 2).

This is what my current select query looks like :

```
SELECT s.city_id, s.city_name, s.country_name, s.population, 
        s.city_long, s.city_lat, s.woeid, s.currency, s.region, 
        s.time_zone, s.area, s.postal_code, n.place_name,  n.capacity, 
        n.place_long, n.place_lat, n.city_id, c.place_id, c.category_id, 
        ss.category_id, ss.category_name, ss.category_icon, cc.photo_id, 
        cc.place_id, cc.photo_name 
FROM city s 
    JOIN place n ON s.city_id = n.city_id 
    JOIN place_cat c ON c.place_id = n.place_id 
    JOIN cat ss ON ss.category_id = c.category_id
    JOIN photo cc ON cc.place_id = n.place_id
```

I don't know if it's an issue with the query or with the way I'm echoing the data. This is how I'm echoing it :

```
 foreach($results as $result) 
{
//
echo '<item>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<city>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<CityName>' . $result['city_name'] . '</CityName>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<CountryName>' . $result['country_name'] . '</CountryName>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<Population>' . $result['population'] . '</Population>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<CityLat>' . $result['city_lat'] . '</CityLat>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<CityLong>' . $result['city_long'] . '</CityLong>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<Woeid>' . $result['woeid'] . '</Woeid>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<Currency>' . $result['currency'] . '</Currency>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<Region>' . $result['region'] . '</Region>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<TimeZone>' . $result['time_zone'] . '</TimeZone>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<Area>' . $result['area'] . '</Area>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<PostalCode>' . $result['postal_code'] . '</PostalCode>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<place>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<PlaceName>' . $result['place_name'] . '</PlaceName>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<Capacity>' . $result['capacity'] . '</Capacity>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<PlaceLat>' . $result['place_lat'] . '</PlaceLat>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<PlaceLong>' . $result['place_long'] . '</PlaceLong>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<Category>' . $result['category_name'] . '</Category>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<Photo>' . $result['photo_name'] . '</Photo>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '</place>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '</city>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '</item>'. PHP_EOL;

}
```

Is there a way to display the data the way I want to (city information to be displayed once, then the corresponding place data to be displayed after)? If so how?

Comment: Please include textual infromation (such as code and output) as text, not images. Unlike images, text can be copied and searched.

Comment: Did you try to include the group by clause in your query ?

Comment: @Atchiiii I've tried to Group it by city_id, but then it just shows the first vaule, instead of all twelve. If I group by place_id, it only displays the first vaule for that too

Comment: What you want, is a basic _control break_ implementation. In your loop over the data (must be properly sorted by city to begin with), you compare the city of the current record, to that of the previous one - and depending on whether they are the same or not, you decide what you need to output.